# Why does my application just stop and does not keep running?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a program (C#) which do this:

1. If I click my left mouse button the mouse should move to the left by a DeltaX.

The problem is that when I run the program, it simple opens the console application and nothing happens. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.
It should keep running and checking if I click the left mouse button or not, and when I click it, the cursor should move to the left by a DeltaX.

code

```
using System.Data;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Teste
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var someClass = new Up();
            someClass.Update();
        }
    }
        public class Up
        {
            [DllImport("user32.dll")] static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey);
            [DllImport("USER32.dll")] static extern short GetKeyState(int nVirtKey);

            int msShootTime = 225;
            System.DateTime lastClick = System.DateTime.Now;

            bool isRunning = true;
            public async void Update()
            {

                while (true)
                {
                    if (isRunning)
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(10);
                        continue;
                    }
                    int res = GetKeyState((int)1);
                    if (res >= 0)
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(1);
                        continue;
                    }
                    Move(-10, 0, true);
                }
            }



            private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
            private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
            private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
            private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;


            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, uint dwData, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);

            public void Move(int xDelta, int yDelta, bool pressDown = false)
            {
                if (pressDown)
                {
                    if (System.DateTime.Now.Subtract(lastClick).TotalMilliseconds < msShootTime)
                    {
                        pressDown = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lastClick = System.DateTime.Now;
                    }
                }

                mouse_event(pressDown ? (MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP) : 0x0001, xDelta, yDelta, 0, UIntPtr.Zero);

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of application types. A console application does not allow you to respond to mouse clicks (at least not easily). You need a GUI application. Then you will be able to respond to mouse clicks. You don't say what environment you are running in so it's hard to give you any further directions.

Comment: @Optimax GetAsyncKeyState() *would* allow to detect a mouse click, here (and move the Mouse Pointer (not the caret), through `mouse_event`). But `isRunning` kind of ruins everything. Then, since when the mouse button is down, the function returns a `SHORT` (which is not a C# `short` :), `res` is never `> 0`, but it will almost always = `0`, so the Mouse Pointer would move constantly (when `isRunning` is out of the picture, that is).

Comment: @Jimi I said "easily". I was hoping "pseudo-GUI" console applications are the thing of the past. The OP didn't say anything about having to use the console. This also looks like a very contrived problem. Like a homework, maybe...

Comment: @Optimax It looks like a test, maybe to understand how this all could work, I cannot say. Anyway, with a couple of changes (as described), it can work.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the `someClass.Update();` call should be changed in `Task.Run(() => someClass.Update());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some mistakes were in code, I've added some comments directly to code

```csharp
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args) // made Main async
    {
        var someClass = new Up();
        await someClass.Update(); // awaiting async method, you didn't wait it and app have to exit immediately
    }
    public class Up
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern short GetKeyState(int nVirtKey);

        // just copied mouse_event and Flags from one of my projects but yours worked too
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern void mouse_event(MouseFlags dwFlags, int dx, int dy, uint dwData, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);

        [Flags]
        private enum MouseFlags : uint 
        {
            MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000,   // If set, dx and dy contain normalized absolute coordinates between 0 and 65535. The event procedure maps these coordinates onto the display surface. Coordinate (0,0) maps onto the upper-left corner of the display surface, (65535,65535) maps onto the lower-right corner.
            MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002,   // The left button is down.
            MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004,     // The left button is up.
            MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020, // The middle button is down.
            MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = 0x0040,   // The middle button is up.
            MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001,       // Movement occurred.
            MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008,  // The right button is down.
            MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x0010,    // The right button is up.
            MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL = 0x0800,      // The wheel has been moved, if the mouse has a wheel.The amount of movement is specified in dwData
            MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN = 0x0080,      // An X button was pressed.
            MOUSEEVENTF_XUP = 0x0100,        // An X button was released.
            MOUSEEVENTF_HWHEEL = 0x01000     // The wheel button is tilted.
        }

        int msShootTime = 225;
        DateTime lastClick = DateTime.Now;

        bool isRunning = false; // it was initially true
        public async Task Update() // async Task
        {

            while (true)
            {
                if (isRunning) // it was always true
                {
                    await Task.Delay(10);
                    continue; // this was always executed
                }
                isRunning = true; // added this
                int res = GetKeyState((int)1);
                if (res >= 0)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1);
                    isRunning = false; // added this
                    continue;
                }
                Move(-10, 0, true);
                isRunning = false; // added this
            }
        }

        public void Move(int xDelta, int yDelta, bool pressDown = false)
        {
            if (pressDown)
            {
                if (System.DateTime.Now.Subtract(lastClick).TotalMilliseconds < msShootTime)
                {
                    pressDown = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    lastClick = System.DateTime.Now;
                }
            }

            // updated for new Flags enum
            // I'm not sure if sending both MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN and MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP will give any effect
            // try to send it sequentially with some delay: DOWN, then UP
            mouse_event(pressDown ? (MouseFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MouseFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP) : MouseFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, xDelta, yDelta, 0, UIntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** Microsoft recommends using [`SendInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) instead of [`mouse_event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event).

> This function has been superseded. Use `SendInput` instead.